# Ionic/UI router broadcast an event on state change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

When i get back to inital state (home) from another page (es. settings), i need to re-call functions to reload data, and these call are handled with cordova events (resume, pause, online..), but on page change none of this events get invoked automaticly,

I thought of doing something like this on page settings:

```
.controller('gobackCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state',
function($scope, $rootScope, $state){

    $scope.goBack = function() {
      $state.go('app.home');
      $rootScope.$broadcast('app-resume', {});
    };

}]);
```

But since controllers are on different states they won't get invoked.

How could i solve this problem?

Comment: They should be invoked cause you are broadcast to the rootScope

Comment: @JsIsAwesome I thought that too but strangly doesn't work that way

Answer (score 0):

Where is your listener on the home state? I'd have a similar issue and I'm using this approach too. And it works well:

I have two states:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('players', {
        url         : '/players',
        controller  : 'PlayersCtrl as players',
        resolve     : {
            playersObj : function(
                $localForage,
                AppSettings
            ) {
                return $localForage.getItem(AppSettings.tables.players);
            }
        },
        templateUrl : 'players.html',
        title       : 'Players'
    })
    .state('players_detail', {
        url         : '/players/:playerId',
        controller  : 'PlayerCtrl as player',
        templateUrl : 'player.html',
        title       : 'Player'
    });
```

In my PlayersCtrl I must use a listener to the update event:

```
function PlayersCtrl(
    $rootScope,
    playersObj    // resolve
) {
    // ViewModel
    var vm = this;
    vm.users = playersObj;

    $rootScope.$on('player.update', function(evt, data) {
        vm.users = data;    // update data on details state
    });
}
```

And in my PlayerCtrl I trigger the update event:

```
function PlayerCtrl(
        $rootScope,
        $state
    ) {

    // ViewModel
    var vm = this;

    vm.player_update = function() {
        // some magic happens here ;)
        …

        // player updated successfully, use broadcast event to notify the PlayersCtrl
        $state.go('players');
        $rootScope.$broadcast('player.update', myUpdatedData);
    };

}
```

Without the broadcast event my players list never updated. With the event it works.

Ciao
Ralf

Comment: That's what i did. I found out that error was in nested views, nested controllers strangly doesn't get events from another state. Only parent state can listen for events emited from another controller.
Thanks for detailed answer.